# How to create a generic .NET type in a native c++ application hosting the CLR (not using C++/CLI)?

Tags: .net, c++, generics, native

In .NET programs I can [create a generic type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) by:

```
 System::Type::MakeGenericType(...)
```

There must be a way to do that in native C++ for a .NET type (with `_TypePtr`). **I am hosting my own CLR instance and not using C++/CLI.** ([Here's an example of how that can be done](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/07/09/use-clr4-hosting-api-to-invoke-net-assembly-from-native-c.aspx).) My approach for that is:

```
_TypePtr BuildGenericType(_TypePtr spGenericType, _TypePtr spTypeArgs[]) 
{
    return spGenericType-> ..... ???
}
```

But there is no method like `MakeGenericType`, and I don't know where to find it. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I tagged this C++/CLI, because I think it's the only way it makes sense. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: no cli its a hosted clr.

Comment: @nemcija: It's really rare to do that, and I edited your question to mention it.

Comment: I deleted my answer which was written before you mentioned CLR hosting.

Comment: _TypePtr is a auto-generated type derived from _comptr_t that you got from using the #import directive in your native code.  The _Type interface is well documented.  It seems stuck in the .NET 1.1 time warp, no MakeGenericType() method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices._type_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Sounds not so good, but I will go on looking for a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found a workaround myself.
At first i need an additional assembly that wraps System::TypeBuilder

```
/// <summary>
/// Wrapper for System::TypeBuilder
/// </summary>
public class TypeBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a generic type out of the given arguments.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="generic">The unqualified generic type.</param>
    /// <param name="typeArgs">The typearguments for the generic type.</param>
    /// <returns>The qualified generic type.</returns>
    public static Type MakeGenericType(Type generic, params Type[] typeArgs)
    {
        return generic.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
    }
}
```

This additional assemly i load from c++

And there i run these sexy lines, where CLRAssembly is an abstraction layer for clr.

```
_TypePtr CLRAssembly::BuildType(_TypePtr spGenericType, _TypePtr spTypeArgs[]) 
{
    LONG index = 0;
    SAFEARRAY* psaArgs = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 1 + (sizeof(spTypeArgs)/sizeof(_TypePtr)));
    SafeArrayPutElement(psaArgs, &index, &_variant_t((IUnknown*)spGenericType, true));
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(spTypeArgs)/sizeof(_TypePtr); i++) {
        index++;
        SafeArrayPutElement(psaArgs, &index, &_variant_t((IUnknown*)spTypeArgs[i], true));
    }

    return (_TypePtr)clraAssemblyHelper->RunMethod(L"AssemblyHelper.TypeBuilder", L"MakeGenericType", psaArgs); 
}
```

Finally i can run my example method like this:

```
DDDElements::Defs* ListDefs::AddNew()
{
    _TypePtr params[1];
    params[0] = clra->BuildType(L"DDD.Elements.Defs");
    _TypePtr spType = clra->BuildType(clra->BuildType(L"DDD.ElementList`1"), params);
    return new DDDElements::Defs(clr, clra, 
        clra->RunMethod(spType, vtCLRObject, L"AddNew")
    );
}
```

Finally it works pretty good. :)

/Solved